# Airline seating using boolean

Tags: javascript, jgrasp

I seem to be having quite a difficult time with this midterm project. It is suppose to ask if you would like `first class` or `coach seating`, then deduct whichever from whichever and offer the choice to book another seat.

I just added the section for dialog options in first class seating and now it is giving me a parse error at "`dialogresult =`" but I can't sort out why. In addition, when it did work, It would successfully loop back to the start, deduct a seat from the count, and then not accept the user input to book again.

I think I just need another set of eyes on this, really confused myself here.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class Midterm2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean coachSeats[] = new boolean[10];
  boolean firstSeats[] = new boolean [5];
  int seatsFull = 0,FirstSeatCount,CoachSeatCount;


  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     firstSeats[i] = false;
     coachSeats[i] = false;

     do{
        FirstSeatCount = 4;
        CoachSeatCount = 9;
        if(firstSeats[i] == false) FirstSeatCount++;
        if(coachSeats[i] == false) CoachSeatCount++;


        int seatClass = Integer.parseInt((String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
           "\n" + FirstSeatCount + " Seats avaliable in First Class "+ 
           "\n" + CoachSeatCount + " Seats avaliable in Coach." +
           "\nPress 1 to reserve a seat in first class" +
           "\nPress 2 to reserve a seat in coach:"));

        if (seatClass == 1){

           if(firstSeats[i] == false)
              firstSeats[i] = true;
           FirstSeatCount = 1;{
           dialogresult = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION; 
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "\nBoarding Pass Details -->" +
                                         "\nSeat number :" + (i+1) +
                                         "\nFirst Class" +
                                         "\nWould you like to reserve another seat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

           if (dialogresult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION); 
           if(dialogresult == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
              break;
                            }                                                       


        if(FirstSeatCount == 0){
           JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("\nNo seats availabe in this class," + 
                         "would you like to travel in another class(y/n):");
                                    }
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a curly brace floating out by itself on the following line that needs to be removed:

```
FirstSeatCount = 1;{
```

Change it to:

```
FirstSeatCount = 1;
```

And that should resolve your parsing issue. Haven't tried compiling the code to see if any other issues exist but this should solve this specific problem.

Also, on a formatting note, do yourself a favor and please don't format your braces in the manner in which you are currently doing it. Although this is subjective, to me there are really only two good practices:

```
if(boolean comparison){
    some code...
}
```

or my personal favorite:

```
if(boolean comparison)
{
    some code...
}
```

I may get flamed or voted down for this by some who like some unorthodox style, but really, doing anything other than these two hurts readability, and as someone who tutors in programming, it's really a big pain in the ass to read code that doesn't follow one of these two conventions. /endrant

Comment: If code isn't set up in one of those two ways, usually I have to spend time refactoring it into one of them before I can work on it. Otherwise I can't read it.

Comment: And many intro level Java courses teach using jGrasp or something similar which has a CSD function to automatically refactor the formatting. An interesting "lifehack" is to generate the CSD, and then remove the CSD immediately after. All of the CSD formatting like lines and such are removed, but the refactoring of the formatting remains behind. Pretty useful for intro Java students who want to see how the code formatting should look versus how it looks when they enter it.